# How to deal with menu hover on touch screen devices(IPad)

Tags: css, ipad, menu, hover

I am using a CSS based  menu in which i used hover effect to show child menu.
I am curious to know how this menu will work on touch screen devices.I tested it on IPad and it doesn't seems to work .

```
<ul id="CSSMenu">
        <li><a class="Home" href="/index.aspx" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">Home</a> </li>
        <li>


<a class="healthcare" href="/healthcare-reform" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">Healthcare Reform</a>

            <ul aclass="healthcare" style="background-color: rgb(51, 153, 153);">
                <li><a href="#">Credits/Subsidies</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Credits/Subsidies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Credits/Subsidies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Credits/Subsidies</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to employ some javascript to allow for tap/click events on touch screens. [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) is a drop-down plugin that uses jQuery to show/hide sub-menu items on hover for desktop machines and on tap events for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting touch screens and dealing with them appropriately is tricky at best. Some devices support both and you can't tell if the end user is using touch or keyboard. Your best bet is to create a structure through CSS or JQuery that replaces hover functionality for touch screen detected devices. Some engineers handle this with double click events but as a end user on a touch screen I find this annoying, others may not.

In your specific case, you could replace the hover on the parent element with a click that shows the child menu and then when anything else is clicked you hide the children.